How to remove the horizontal scrollbar everytime v-select dropdown area is clicked
How to remove this horinzontal scrollbar that is appearing everytime i click the v-select data items.It will only popup 1sec then it will be gone Ive already tried using overflow-x ,y  ,and others methods but all didnt work.
I already tried adding height in the v-card and width but still it didnt fix the issue.

This is my vuejs
    <template>
    <div class="vue-container" v-if="state.isCreated">
        <div class="vue-content">
            <v-layout d-flex align-center justify-center style='height: 80vh'>
                <v-row justify="center">
                    <v-col col="3" xs="3" sm="3" md="3" lg="3">
                        <v-card tile class="transaction-card">
                            <v-simple-table dense>
                                <div class="table-header">
                                    <div class="title">
                                        <span>PAYMENT PRIORITY MANAGEMENT</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </v-simple-table>
                            <v-form class="form-section">
                                <v-simple-table
                                    dense
                                    class="grouped-rows striped bordered highlight"
                                >
                                    <template>
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th align="center" width="70">
                                                    Priority #
                                                </th>
                                                <th align="center" width="200">
                                                    Amortization
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                    </template>
                                    <template>
                                        <tbody
                                            v-for="(item, index) in bracketBalance"
                                            :key="index"
                                        >
                                            <tr class="ba-1">
                                                <td align="center">
                                                    {{ index + 1 }}.
                                                </td>
                                                <td
                                                    v-if="showupdate"
                                                    class="text-center"
                                                >
                                                    <v-select
                                                        :error="
                                                            item.error
                                                        "
                                                        :items="priority.data"
                                                        :boundInput="item.tempid"
                                                        
                                                        solo
                                                        dense
                                                        height="5px"
                                                        hide-details
                                                        @change="
                                                            changeItems(
                                                                $event,
                                                                index,
                                                                item.tempid
                                                            )
                                                        "
                                                    ></v-select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td v-else-if="initialView">
                                                    {{ item.priority }}
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr class="ba-1">
                                                <td align="center">8.</td>
                                                <td>Principal</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </template>
                                </v-simple-table>
                            </v-form>
                            <v-layout
                                align-center
                                justify-center
                                style="padding-top: 10px"
                            >
                                <v-flex>
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <v-btn
                                            small
                                            v-if="showedit"
                                            tile
                                            v-on:click="editBracketBalance"
                                            >Edit</v-btn
                                        >
                                        <v-btn
                                            small
                                            v-if="showupdate"
                                            tile
                                            v-on:click="checkError"
                                            class="mr-10"
                                            >Save</v-btn
                                        >
                                        <v-btn
                                            v-if="showupdate"
                                            tile
                                            small
                                            v-on:click="initialView"
                                            >Back</v-btn
                                        >
                                    </div>
                                </v-flex>
                            </v-layout>
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-layout>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.shortcutkey {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    text-indent: 8px;
}

/* ::v-deep .v-select-list > .v-list-item.v-list-item--disabled {
    color: black !important;
} */
::v-deep .v-select .v-select__selection--disabled{
  color: black !important;
}
</style>


i think .form-section{overflow-x: hidden;} should help

I've tried it , it is still appearing horizontal scrollbar i have no idea what causing it and dispapper after 1 sec.

Inspect the thing with your devtools to find out what it is/where it comes from.

There's a lot more CSS that needs to be provided to fully reproduce the issue.  Devtools DOM inspector should be able to tell you what exact element is the problem, but if you can't figure it out, you'll need to provide more complete code that others can debug for you.  Provide codepen demo or other sandbox/repo if possible. Also, remove as much unnecessary code as possible.  Reproduction case should be minimal
